# Stratified Sampling in R with RF models

Tags: python, r, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataset from a csv file (consider dataset.csv) with Binary representation of features(381 features) and 11 classes. Here below is a sample representation.

```
#features->      A,B,C,D,E,......Y,X,Class

raw1             0,1,1,1,0,......1,1,9
raw2             0,1,0,0,0,......0,0,8
raw3             0,1,1,1,0,......1,0,8
....
raw54000         0,1,0,0,0,......1,0,3
```

The problem I am facing is the imbalance in classes. Therefore, I am to incorporate stratified sampling by taking 250 instances from each class and create 500 trees for bootstrapping.Since I have 11 classes each tree will be trained using 11*250= 2750 instances. I am very much familiar with `weka` but there seems to not have an option for this.

Other data analysis tasks were done by Python mostly using pandas. But someone told me this can be  easily done by `R` which I have very little experience. If some one can guide me how to do this in either way using `Python(pandas)/scikit learning` or `R`, I am much grateful

Comment: Stratified sampling will preserve imbalances present in the original data set. Perhaps, what you need is equal sampling of classes. If you're modeling in Python, it's achieved automatically in sklearn's [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) by setting `class_weight="auto"`

Comment: I would recommend looking in to the [caret package](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html).  It is made for predictive modelling and has splitting functions for this exact problem.

Comment: @bushmanov Thanks I may try that

Comment: @cdeterman the thing is they may have the exact solution. But I am not much familiar with R. Thats why I posted entire problem with the data set structure itself so that some  one could be able to point me some sample codes I could try

Comment: @IsuraNirmal that is why I provided the link.  There is lots of sample code you can try at that website.